# ARIA input fields do not have accessible names

Tags: html, angular, accessibility, wai-aria, lighthouse

I have run my accessibility test in google chrome light house for my angular application and getting the following error

[image]

I have added 'aria-labelledby', but doesn't seems to be working. can anyone assist me to fix this. below is the html code which is giving me this error.

```
<div class="heading form-group col-md-4 col-xs-12">
     <label for="fuels">Fuel Filter</label>
     <ng-select class="oss-ngselect" [items]="fuelType" bindLabel="name"
           placeholder="View All" [(ngModel)]="searchPremiseFuelType" [dropdownPosition]="'bottom'" 
           id="fuels" name="fuels" (change)="changeFuelType(searchPremiseFuelType.type)"
           aria-labelledby="fuels">
     </ng-select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`aria-labelledby` is used to identify another element, using its ID, to serve as the name for the current element.

Please try giving `aria-label="fuels"` instead of `aria-labelledby`

For more information, I would suggest to go through the following blog ::
https://web.dev/aria-name/

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `aria-label` and `aria-labelledby` on a `ng-select` is that the label does not focus the `<select>` as expected when clicked as it is still not properly associated with the control.

I believe that the correct way to do this in Angular (it has been a while since I played with it!) is to use the `labelForId` attribute on the control itself, which points back to the `<label>` and should be the same as the label's `for` (so `labelForID="test"` and `labelForId="test"`).

So in your above example we would add the `labelForId` attribute as follows:

```
<div class="heading form-group col-md-4 col-xs-12">
     <label for="fuels">Fuel Filter</label>
     <ng-select class="oss-ngselect" [items]="fuelType" bindLabel="name"
           placeholder="View All" [(ngModel)]="searchPremiseFuelType" [dropdownPosition]="'bottom'" 
           id="fuels" name="fuels" (change)="changeFuelType(searchPremiseFuelType.type)" labelForId="fuels">
     </ng-select>
</div>
```

Could you try that OP and confirm if it works (without the `aria-labelledby`) as I couldn't remember how to set an Angular project up quickly enough for a simple test like this!